# Eigenvalues of tensor products

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say I have two matrices $A$ and $B$, and I know both are diagonalisable, both are $n\times n$ matrices and can be written as
\begin{equation}
A=\sum_i a_i|a_i\rangle\langle a_i|
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
B=\sum_i b_i|b_i\rangle\langle b_i|
\end{equation}
Now imagine I have the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
A\otimes B+B\otimes A
\end{equation}
Is there anything which can be said in general about the eigenvalues of the $n^2\times n^2$ matrix in general? I would imagine there is some way of writing the eigenvalues of the joint matrix in terms of the known eigenvalues $a_i$ and $b_i$.

It may be helpful to write
\begin{equation}
A\otimes B+B\otimes A=\sum_{i,j}a_ib_j\left(|a_i\rangle\langle a_i|\otimes\sum_{k,l}\langle a_k|b_j\rangle\langle b_j|a_l\rangle|a_k\rangle\langle a_l|+\sum_{k,l}\langle a_k|b_j\rangle\langle b_j|a_l\rangle|a_k\rangle\langle a_l|\otimes|a_i\rangle\langle a_i|\right)
\end{equation}

In general $A\otimes B+B\otimes A$ is not diagonal for $A$ and $B$ diagonal, however for the example I want $A$ is positive and $B$ is anti-Hermitian, so I do observe that $A\otimes B+B\otimes A$ is always diagonal.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3309632/202425 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1742207/202425